# Angular2 not updated properly

Tags: angular

I cloned https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter in my project for explore angular2 and express.

What I want to is just "Hello World" level, so it looks complicated I deleted every files in **modules** folder.

and I deleted injecting modules in **app.modules.ts** file.

so my app.modules.ts is below :

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAuth } from "angular2-jwt";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { NgSemanticModule } from "ng-semantic";

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        NgSemanticModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        provideAuth({
            globalHeaders: [{"Content-type": "application/json"}],
            newJwtError: true,
            noTokenScheme: true
        })
    ],
    declarations: [  AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

as you can see, there is no other module in imports and declarations.

and I edit app.component.ts, the root component. like below:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: `<h1> Hello Angular 2 </h1>`
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

What I expected just showing "Hello Angular 2".

but the browser still request deleted page. the component was deleted. Where and why angular2 request that file?

Is my way wrong? I am having problem since yesterday, It looks very difficult to setting.

[image]

Comment: Angular 2 isn't for hello world level stuff. You should use ReactJS, it's for hello world level all the way to enterprise. Angular 2 is meant to lock in workers to a toolset so its easy to onboard new employees in high turnover companies.

Comment: @Noitidart But the company want to build ionic app, ionic is based on angular right? I have to use ng2 on my situation... I have background express+nodejs+mongodb but first time in ng2.

Answer (score 1):

try **removing** `providers` from `app.module.ts` :

```
    providers: [
            provideAuth({
                globalHeaders: [{"Content-type": "application/json"}],
                newJwtError: true,
                noTokenScheme: true
            })
        ]
```

our authService is implemented in `home.component.ts` (https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter/blob/master/client/modules/home/home.component.ts) and it's being called.

Answer (score -1):

What does index.html look like? It must contain the "app" tag